# Is there a problem updating MS Teams using teh Graph SDL

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have tried to update the `DisplayName` of a Team. No error is returned, but Display Name is *not* updating.

Is this an error with the service?

Example Snippet Below

```
private static async void testUpdate(AzureADConnection azureADConnection, String TeamNameId)
{
    Team originalTeam = AuthenticationHelper
        .graphClient(azureADConnection)
        .Teams[TeamNameId]
        .Request()
        .GetAsync()
        .Result;

    Team Update = new Team();
    Team Updated = new Team();

    Update.DisplayName = "New Team Name";

    Updated = await AuthenticationHelper
        .graphClient(azureADConnection)
        .Teams[TeamNameId]
        .Request()
        .UpdateAsync(Update);
    string gh;
    gh = "ssss";
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. What is `gh` and where is this used? What is the purpose of `originalTeam`? What _are_ you getting back? What is `AuthenticationHelper`?

Comment: Hi Marc, gh is just a place where I can put a breakpoint, Original team let's me verify the team id is correct and let's me view the associated properties, AuthenticationHelper gets my token for MS Graph. The original team is returning the expected result. However when into try to update the team, it is not updating

Comment: What _are_ you getting back?

Comment: Hi Marc, Im getting null

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. You should be getting back _something_ (a `400`, `404`, `401`, etc.). I suggest looking at the actual HTTP call on the wire using Fiddler or WireShark. Even a failed call will generate an HTTP response with a JSON payload.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried updating the Team displayName using the PowerShell modules and it doesn't update.  The response is a 204, which would explain why the return value is null.

This looks like a service issue to me.

Comment: As someone who is trying to build functionality into our platform using the Graph API, how would i know if a service is down/in error

Comment: @AndyLynch  If something isn't working in code, I tend to try the same call via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)  If it doesn't work there, then either it isn't supported or it is a service error.  You can raise a support ticket against Microsoft Graph in the Azure portal